# When I write a game for Windows, should I use kivy or pygame?

Tags: python, touch, kivy

I have to create a game in Python for University and it should run on Windows.
Now I have found `kivy` and I am asking myself, if `kivy` is even better than `pygame` or is it just for touch displays and I better use `pygame`?

We don't have touch displays btw!

The questions are, is kivy easier to program, easier to learn or more efficiently?

P.S.: I'm aware of the fact, that pygame is part of kivy!

Comment: Pygame is not part of kivy. We used to use it as a default windowing backend (to get an opengl context + input handling), but have now switched to SDL2 everywhere except Android, where SDL2 is working but not yet the default target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally find `kivy` better than `pygame`. The latter one is kind of outdated and doesn't get much support today while `kivy` is still growing and gaining new possibilities. It's also not true that `kivy` is only for touch displays. It's completely multiplatform so you can create a `kivy` app for almost any operating system without needing to change anything in your code! Although you might get a little bit better performance with `pygame`, `kivy` is much more intuitive framework and if you don't aim to create a Crysis I'd go with `kivy`. Cheers!

P.S. You couldn't make anything like Crysis even with `pygame` :D If you want to create a 3D game in Python you better use `kivent`, a 3D engine written in C with Python API dedicated for `kivy`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will use Kivy!

Comment: Just a little heads up: kivent is NOT a 3D engine. It wouldn't be super hard to implement 3D support, but atm there is no such thing in kivent.
Kivent is still nice if you have to deal with a lot of dynamic objects,
'